# How to reshape xarray data with new dimensions

Tags: python, python-xarray

I'm fairly new to the `xarray` library, and I am stuck in a what it seems a fairly straight-forward task. I have global climate data in a `GRIB` file for different 30-km grids. The data looks like this:

```py
<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:     (time: 736, values: 542080)
Coordinates:
    number      int64 0
  * time        (time) datetime64[ns] 2007-12-01 ... 2008-03-01T21:00:00
    step        timedelta64[ns] 00:00:00
    surface     int64 0
    latitude    (values) float64 89.78 89.78 89.78 ... -89.78 -89.78 -89.78
    longitude   (values) float64 0.0 20.0 40.0 60.0 ... 280.0 300.0 320.0 340.0
    valid_time  (time) datetime64[ns] 2007-12-01 ... 2008-03-01T21:00:00
Dimensions without coordinates: values
Data variables:
    t2m         (time, values) float32 247.30748 247.49889 ... 225.18036
Attributes:
    GRIB_edition:            1
    GRIB_centre:             ecmf
    GRIB_centreDescription:  European Centre for Medium-Range Weather Forecasts
    GRIB_subCentre:          0
    Conventions:             CF-1.7
    institution:             European Centre for Medium-Range Weather Forecasts
    history:                 2020-01-21T09:40:59 GRIB to CDM+CF via cfgrib-0....
```

And that is fine. I can access to different time instances and plot stuff, even access to the data per cell using `data.t2m.data`. But, the data is indexed only by `time` and `value`, this last one is -I assume- a cell number identifier, but is not reading `latitude` and `longitude` as meaningful dimensions.

On the documentation, the authors use `airtemp` reanalysis data as an example, these data is indexed by `lat`, `lon`, and `time`, and that is what I want to do with my dataset.

```
<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:  (lat: 25, lon: 53, time: 2920)
Coordinates:
  * lat      (lat) float32 75.0 72.5 70.0 67.5 65.0 ... 25.0 22.5 20.0 17.5 15.0
  * lon      (lon) float32 200.0 202.5 205.0 207.5 ... 322.5 325.0 327.5 330.0
  * time     (time) datetime64[ns] 2013-01-01 ... 2014-12-31T18:00:00
Data variables:
    air      (time, lat, lon) float32 ...
Attributes:
    Conventions:  COARDS
    title:        4x daily NMC reanalysis (1948)
    description:  Data is from NMC initialized reanalysis\n(4x/day).  These a...
    platform:     Model
    references:   http://www.esrl.noaa.gov/psd/data/gridded/data.ncep.reanaly...
```

There is a straight forward way of doing this re-indexing in the `xarray` environment? I guess I can just simply extract the `numpy` arrays and jump to `pandas` or something else, but I find the `xarray` library really powerful and useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way might be to manually construct a `pandas.MultiIndex` from the latitude and longitude variables, assign it as the coordinate for the `values` dimension, and then unstack the Dataset:

```py
import pandas as pd

index = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays(
    [ds.longitude.values, ds.latitude.values], names=['lon', 'lat']
)
ds['values'] = index
reshaped = ds.unstack('values')
```

For more on this, see [this section](http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/reshaping.html#stack-and-unstack) under the "Reshaping and reorganizing data" section of the xarray documentation.

Comment: The memory can be an issue though.