# Plotting Gaussian Gridded data in cartopy

Tags: python, reshape, python-xarray, cartopy

I have an xarray dataset with gridded data. Using another thread [How to reshape xarray data with new dimensions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59845442/how-to-reshape-xarray-data-with-new-dimensions)
I was able to successfully make the latitude and longitude coordinates into dimensions however the issue that I am running into is with plotting the data.

It seems that the values of the data are not conforming to the new dimensions and shape of the dataset as most of the values become nan after I reshape the dataset.

```py
import xarray as xr
import pandas as pd
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

sl_forecasts = xr.open_zarr(
    'gs://gcp-public-data-arco-era5/co/single-level-forecast.zarr/', 
    chunks={'time': 48},
    consolidated=True,
)

sl_forecasts = sl_forecasts.sel(time = '2021-02-27T06:00:00.000000000')
sl_forecasts = sl_forecasts.sel(step = '3600000000000')
sl_forecasts = sl_forecasts['tp']

index = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays(
    [sl_forecasts.longitude.values,sl_forecasts.latitude.values], names=['longitude', 'latitude']
)
sl_forecasts['values'] = index
sl_forecasts = sl_forecasts.unstack('values')

proj = ccrs.PlateCarree()
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 8), subplot_kw=dict(projection=proj))

tp = sl_forecasts.values
lon = sl_forecasts['longitude'].values
lat = sl_forecasts['latitude'].values
ax.coastlines()
tp_plot = ax.contourf(lon, lat, tp, transform=proj, cmap='Blues')
```

how can I get this data to plot in cartopy?

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: @mkrieger1 how I can get the data to plot

Comment: What do you get from these: (1) `tp.shape`, (2) `lon.shape`, (3) `lat.shape`. Is (1)=(2)x(3)?

Answer (score 0):

Although I don't know exactly what your data or the error message looks like, this is how I would plot the data:

```py
import xarray as xr
import pandas as pd
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np


sl_forecasts = xr.open_zarr(
    'gs://gcp-public-data-arco-era5/co/single-level-forecast.zarr/', 
    chunks={'time': 48},
    consolidated=True,
)

sl_forecasts = sl_forecasts.sel(
    time = '2021-02-27T06:00:00.000000000',
    step = '3600000000000'
)['tp']
sl_forecasts['values'] = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays(
    [sl_forecasts.longitude.values,sl_forecasts.latitude.values], 
    names=['longitude', 'latitude']
)
sl_forecasts = sl_forecasts.unstack('values')

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 8), subplot_kw=dict(projection=proj))

tp_plot = sl_forecasts['tp'].plot.contouf(
    ax=ax, 
    proj=ccrs.PlateCarree()
)
ax.coastlines()
```

If you plot xarray data sets, you can plot them directly using the `.plot(...)` method. This assumes that the dataset is 2-dimensional. If you have a dataset that is 3-dimensional, for example with "lat", "lon" and "time" as dimensions, then you could also do the following:

```py
# ... 
ds["variable"].mean("time").plot(ax=ax, proj=ccrs.PlateCarree())
```

As an example, I have an illustration here:

[image]

Let me know what you think.

Comment: hey, thank you for the advice, however your first example of how you would plot the data does not work

Comment: So what is the problem?

Comment: try using the code that you first provided but switch your tp_plot with this line of code:

    tp_plot = ax.contourf(
        sl_forecasts.values,
        cmap='jet'
    )

the data does not plot properly. Let me know if you see it.

Comment: What is the error message? For me it looks like that you are trying to plot data that is not 3-dimensional. Idk your data but maybe the part `sl_forecasts = sl_forecasts.sel(time='2021-02-27T06:00:00.000000000',step='3600000000000')['tp']` removes the required dimensions. What is the shape of your data set?